# Question about "RMAN-06169:" and Oracle

Tags: oracle, rman

When i typed the command "backup database" it mentioned

"RMAN-06169: could not read file header for datafile 5 error reason 4..."etc
[image]

and then i checked the STATUS of the datafile 5

(look at the picture)

[image]

so i tried to recover ,it didn't work.

it told me that "ORA-00283: recovery session canceled due to errors
ORA-01110: data file 5: '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/abc/abc.dbf'
ORA-01157: cannot identify/lock data file 5 - see DBWR trace file
ORA-01110: data file 5: '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/abc/abc.dbf'
(datafile 7 is the same situation.)"

It reminded me that i once delected the document-abc under the graphic interface,which meant that i didn't use the command to delect the file.

so i tried to alter the datafile 5 and datafile 7..  it didn't work also.

how to alter the datafile 5 and 7? and backup database?
thanks very much~！

Comment: what actually want to do that? want to take backup of your database through RMAN or want to see the backup file through RMAN.

Comment: i want to backup full database.but there is something wrong with the datafile 5 and 7.  the datafile 5 and 7 is useless and i want to alter them,

Comment: I am not able to see your 'Alter Command' could you please edit  in your question. what you are trying to run ALTER command in SQL or RMAN command prompt.

Comment: @MdHaidarAliKhan Um...could you tell me how to solve the problem about"RMAN-06169: could not read file header for datafile 5 error reason 4"

Comment: @MdHaidarAliKhan I mean"alter database datafile 5 offline drop;"←

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command to `SKIP` the `offline and corrupted` datafiles:

```
BACKUP DATABASE
    SKIP INACCESSIBLE
    SKIP OFFLINE;
```

> SKIP INACCESSIBLE: Inaccessible datafiles. A datafile is only considered inaccessible if it cannot be read. Some offline datafiles can still be read because they exist on disk. Others have been deleted or moved and so cannot be
>   read, making them inaccessible.
>
> SKIP OFFLINE: skipping Offline datafiles;

Details: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10734/rcmbackp.htm